# Chromecast - Application not working for rtsp video addresses(android)

Tags: android, video, chromecast

I am working on an android project having feature of video casting with chromecast device.The application is working fine the http address video but not working for rtsp.
    I am using these two urls

```
private String videoURL = "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/mp4/DesigningForGoogleCast.mp4"; // working fine

private String videoURL = "rtsp://mpv.cdn3.bigCDN.com:554/bigCDN/definst/mp4:bigbuckbunnyiphone_400.mp4"; // not showing video in cast device but running in android VideoView
```

Here is my code when getting the session started in casting device

```
  @Override
    public void onSessionStarted(CastSession session, String sessionId) {
        mCastSession = session;
        Log.d("session status","started....");
        MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);

        movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, videoTitle);
        movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, videoHead);
        movieMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(smallImageUrl)));
        movieMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(largemageUrl)));

        MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(videoURL)
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setContentType("videos/mp4")
                .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
                .setStreamDuration(10 * 1000)
                .build();
        Log.d("cast session", ""+mCastSession);
        RemoteMediaClient remoteMediaClient = mCastSession.getRemoteMediaClient();
        remoteMediaClient.load(mediaInfo, true, 0);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
```

I am getting some answer like chromecast doest not support rtsp addresses. I am not sure why? What can be the alternate solution for rtsp video, if it is true.

Answer (score 0):

RTSP protocol is not supported on Chromecast. You need to find an alternative supported stream for your video (e.g., many WebCams provide rtsp and also http streams).

Comment: Thanks Ali for your response. Will I have to make receiver application as I have the only option of playing rtsp and hls address videos? I am not clear.

Comment: I am not sure how you are planning to provide support for rtsp through a custom receiver; I believe that is not doable if the platform (chromecast) doesn't support that protocol.